# What is the correct way to cite the "Harvard General Inquirer Dictionary" in a paper?

Tags: dictionary

I would like to cite the Harvard General Inquirer Dictionary in a paper, but I am not able to find the correct reference. Should I cite the homepage, the manual or one of these references available in [General Inquirer manual](http://www.wjh.harvard.edu/%7Einquirer/j1_1/manual/manual.html#StoneEtal1966)?

1
Edward F. Kelly and Philip J. Stone.
Computer Recognition of English Word Senses.
North-Holland Publishing, 1975.

2
Andrew Perrin.
Coderead: A mutiplatform coding engine for text-based data.
In American Sociological Association annual meeting, August 2000.

3
Philip J. Stone, Dexter C. Dunphy, Marshall S. Smith, Daniel M. Ogilvie, and associates.
The General Inquirer: A Computer Approach to Content Analysis.
MIT Press, 1966.

I usually cite python libraries and I always can find the correct reference to the tool. They make it clear. My question is how people cite this dictionary. I was not able to find a place that says “if you use it, please cite...” see for instance scikit-learn.org/0.16/about.html

Comment: Google has no results for "Harvard General Inquiry Dictionary"...

Answer (score 4):

There is no unique standard for the form of citations, either in linguistics, or in general. The journal (etc.) that you are submitting to has it's own citation style. Since this is apparently an online archive, that is especially up to the journal, but typically requires supplying a permanent URL and an access date (i.e. you are using *which* version?). Since this is apparently a dead link, the editor may also ask for a link to the Wayback machine copy. So ask the editor.

Comment: Sorry. I think that was not my question. I usually cite python libraries and I always can find the correct reference to the tool. They make it clear. My question is how people cite this dictionary. I was not able to find a place that says “if you it, please cite...” see for instance https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/about.html

Comment: So you are asking us what they want you to do, and not what the conventions are for academic citation of web pages?

Comment: yes!!! Sure! I want to know how to cite them in a correct way that I can acknowledge that it is an important source.